# Move a div below another div at a certain screen width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a mobile website with 4 banners that appear side by side. When I get to a certain screen width, I want 2 of them to drop below the other 2. Part of the problem is that I have used `width: 24.96%` to obtain the right total width of all 4 divs to fit the body.

**CSS**

```
.small_banners .banner_block {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 24.96%; }

.small_banners {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 15px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="small_banners">
    <div class="banner_block">
      <div>
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner_block">
      <div>
        2nd piece of content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner_block">
      <div>
        3rd piece of content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner_block">
      <div>
        The 4th piece of content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When the screen reaches 958px I want the 3rd and 4th divs to drop below the 1st and 2nd, using a simple media query: `@media all and (max-width: 958px) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work.

```
 @media (max-width: 958px) {
        .small_banners .banner_block{
           width:50% !important;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kishan's method does indeed work if implemented correctly! Here's a fiddle that illustrates using the `css` `max-width` property to change the width of the 4  `.banner_block` elements depending on the screen width.

https://jsfiddle.net/evc670st/1/

Note elements with class `banner_block`  use `display:block` and `float:left` to stack horizontally. If you don't want to `float` these elements, you can use `display: inline-block`, but make sure there is no whitespace in between your html markup.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Strangely it's not working for me on my live version, so something's messing around with it. http://www.sturdrinks.eu/shop/ You'll see the 4 banners below the main banner. Any ideas? I'm stumped on something pretty basic!

Comment: Your css looks like it's autogenerated by your CMS, but generally you want to put the last css media query you wish to apply at the bottom - order in css is very important! In your css a media "all" query is overrulling the styles. Best way to find out what is happening is to right click on one of the div's with class `banner_block` and choose inspect element to open the developer toolbar. Then, look at which computed styles for each html element to see why your styles are getting overrulled. Good luck!